# When does ECS do a Docker pull

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

If I stop/start a task on an ECS cluster will that pull the latest Docker image.

OR

Do I need to create an new task?

Comment: See if this answers your question https://serverfault.com/questions/682340/update-the-container-of-a-service-in-amazon-ecs

Answer (score 1):

ECS will pull the image(s) you specify in your task definition every time you start a task.

> If I stop/start a task on an ECS cluster will that pull the latest Docker image. OR Do I need to create an new task?

I think you're confusing tasks and task definitions.  Tasks cannot be restarted, so every time you start a task it creates a new one.  Task definitions describe how to create tasks and contain the reference to the image.  ECS will pull every time you start a task, so you do not need to create a new task definition each time.